# Adding Watcher or Evaluate object in Rider Unity will cause to throw exception in debug mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net, rider

Recently I Got problem with Newtonsoft class in unity. in the actual code every thing works fine but when I add watcher to JToken object I get blow error:

> Exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' was thrown: Method
> MetadataMethod(6000A0D Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken::SelectToken,1p)
> could not be resolved on type
> MetadataClassType(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)

or some times getting this one:

> Exception of type 'System.Security.VerificationException' was thrown:
> Method with token 100665429 not found in type
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions

but the thing is it's only happens when I get it in debug and with watcher or Evaluate Expression.

some times it works fine but almost most of the time I get this error in debug mode.

in actual game the data is properly get and there is no problem in there I even assign data to string and it works fine in game but I just can't see the data in any way with debug mode on.

I try to remove All .csproj file and it doesn't work.

also have to mention it mostly happens to `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace not `Newtonsoft.Json` itself. so I can for example evaluate `JObject` but when I try to Evaluate `JObject.SelectToken` function I will get this error.

Comment: Are you using the library from the package manager or the stock one ?

Comment: I use stock one, couldn't replace the newtonsoft-for-unity because of conflict issue. the stock version is 2.0.2.

Comment: This library has been expressly updated by Unity due to its popularity and compatibility issues, you should strictly use the one from package manager or you'll get all sort of funny issues. Create a git branch to make this upgrade and fix all the code, once you got it right, merge your changes back to your main branch.

Comment: Ok just a question, do you mean getting the [Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity) or you mean the one unity provided in package manager [Newton Soft](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/changelog/CHANGELOG.html). because I already adding the second one and still got the issue.

Comment: I meant the second so you seem okay at this point. As for your actual problem, indeed this does happen sometimes in Rider, I'd suggest you search for/open an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER.

Comment: Thank you, actually I check the forum but see noting also I add new post in there too and still I  didn't get anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's the joys of using Rider... personally I switched back to VS because it's more predictable even though Rider has nice features ‍♂️

Comment: Please report this in Rider with Help - Report a Bug, agree to attach logs. Make sure to reproduce the issue prior to submitting. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I will report it. your right @aybe looks like I should switch too :)

Comment: @FDM.Pro Personally I wouldn't switch if it's solely for this very bug as there are many great features that you may like in Rider. But in the end, everyone is free to decide!